# Find empty DOM elements and remove them with Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three columns, each of them containing a `DIV`. These `DIV`'s are filled with data but it occasionally happens, that these `DIV`'s are empty and in that case they screw up my layout. Now I want to check if the `DIV`'s are filled with data (html) and if not, to remove them. I made some `if`-statements but I'm sure this can be done smoother.

Here is my js code:

```
if ($.trim($(".fcol1").html()) =='') {
   $(".fcol1").remove();
}

if($.trim($(".fcol2").html()) == '') {
   $(".fcol2").remove();
}

if($.trim($(".fcol3").html()) == '') {
   $(".fcol3").remove();
}
```

So, is there a way to shorten this code?

Comment: Add more description?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they're **truly** empty, you can do:

```
$(".fcol1:empty, .fcol2:empty, .fcol3:empty").remove();
```

...but if they have even a blank text node in them, that won't work. You could do:

```
$(".fcol1, .fcol2, .fcol3").filter(function() {
    return !$.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).remove();
```

---

Note that your original code only checks the **first** element matching the selector and, if that one element is empty, deletes **all** matching elements whether they're empty or not. E.g., if the *first* `.fcol1` is empty, **all** `.fcol1`s are deleted. (Perhaps you probably only have one of each...)

Comment: Or for futur readers, could use `:blank` too in CSS4 to handle any white spaces  https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-blank-pseudo

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks alot! :-)